# Error while bundling Rails application (missing gems?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

Note: this is my first attempt with Ruby and Rails!

Once I've installed everything I tried to create a new app with

```
rails new rubyapp
```

the command created everything and then the bundler started. While running it stopped at

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/build_info/coffee-script-source-1.6.2.info
An error occurred while installing coffee-script-source (1.6.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install coffee-script-source -v '1.6.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

well.. no problem.. let's install this..

```
sudo gem install -p http://myproxy:8080 coffee-script-source -v '1.6.2'
Installing ri documentation for coffee-script-source-1.6.2
1 gem installed
```

Good. Try again.

```
bundle install
```

and stopped here:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/build_info/execjs-1.4.0.info
An error occurred while installing execjs (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install execjs -v '1.4.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

!!!

Needless to say that I've installed this, tried again and the same error came up with different "gems".

My question is: **is there a command to find if I've everything I need installed** without doing these steps tons of times (also because they're pretty slow..)?

I've also tried bundling with `sudo` but maybe it's not working for the proxy.. : /

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try `export http_proxy=http://myproxy:8080`. And run bundler again?

Comment: I already exported it (`echo $HTTP_PROXY` is working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to help anyone still looking (I presume you fixed it in the end) running the command `sudo chown myuser:myuser /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/build_info/` (where `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/build_info/` is the directory referenced in the error) fixed this.

Comment: Well, in the end I've just gone through all the required installation but I guess that this command should work. I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to install RVM (or rbenv) to install/uninstall ruby interpreters. Ruby interpreter bundled with Mac OS X is too old. Also gem installation procedure for system ruby interpreter requires superuser privileges.

If it is your first attempt to Rails world, please, start it with right tools, and actual ruby version (1.9.3).

Here you can find how to install RVM: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Good luck!

Comment: I'm aware this is quite a bit later than this was posted, but I'm using RVM and I have exactly the same error. I wouldn't want anyone to go through the pain of installing it to fix this when it won't work :)

Comment: Here is some tips about how to prepare your mac environment to install RVM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430408/installing-ruby-on-rails-on-mac-is-failing/15431665#15431665

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't fix the error. It's a permissions problem that occurs even with RVM installed